# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: c++, python, windows

Когда пытаюсь выполнить скрипт bimbam.py выходит эта ошибка:

> File "mmfparser\bytereader.pyx", line 195, in
>   mmfparser.bytereader.ByteReader.read (./mmfparser/bytereader.cpp:3093)
>   OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Линии в bytereader.pyx с 195 по 197:

> cpdef read(self, int size = -1): cdef char * buf cdef size_t
>   read_bytes

Линии с 3092 по 3096 в bytereader.cpp:

> if (values[0]) { pyx_v_size = __Pyx_PyInt_As_int(values[0]); if
>   (unlikely((__pyx_v_size == (int)-1) && PyErr_Occurred()))
>   {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 195; __pyx_clineno =
>   __LINE; goto __pyx_L3_error;} } else { __pyx_v_size = ((int)-1); }

https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=bc2c0be906a79340&id=BC2C0BE906A79340%2123325&authkey=!AMftYeIShSuzmBk - ссылка на anaconda-mode3 (там все скрипты и bimbam.py)

python v 2.7.10 (обязательно)

cython 0.21.2

microsoft visual c++ compiler for python

Что сделать чтобы ошибка не появлялась?

Comment: А сколько байт в самом деле хотите прочесть? (распечатайте аргумент перед вызовом)

Comment: 5 110 571 байт.